# How to "beautify"/"simplify" this code for handling arrow keys and tabIndex?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering how to "beautify"/"simplify" the below code:

```js
function handleKeyDown (e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    e.preventDefault()
    myCustomEvent(e)
    return
  }
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.key === 'ArrowDown'
      ? document &&
        document.activeElement &&
        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling &&
        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus()
      : document &&
        document.activeElement &&
        document.activeElement.previousElementSibling &&
        document.activeElement.previousElementSibling.focus()
  }
}
```

It seems too verbose to me.

**Is there something I'm doing wrong?**

**How can I write it better?**

Comment: Both beauty and simplicity are in the eye of the beholder, and therefore answers will not be objective. Please [edit] your question to limit the question to objectively measurable attributes. Or, if the code works, and you've written it yourself, you can get a review of all of the code at [codereview.se], but check their help center first.

Answer (score 3):

You can use optional chaining `document?.activeElement?.nextElementSibling?.focus?.()`

Comment: I believe this will still throw an error. I think you need `focus?.()`

Answer (score 2):

```
   function isActive(){
      return document && document.activeElement
    }
   if ( isActive()) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.key === 'ArrowDown' ? 
        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling &&
        document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus()
    : e.key === 'ArrowUp' ?
        document.activeElement.previousElementSibling &&
        document.activeElement.previousElementSibling.focus()
    :null
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

My point of you for your code is, as suggested by @Alesky, use the optional chaining operator to get element where focus need to acquired or assign the comparison result of `e.key === 'ArrowDown'` to a variable, and call the `focus()` method to it.

```
...
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault()
    var baseEl = document && document.activeElement ; 
    var focusEl = e.key === 'ArrowDown'
      ? baseEl && document.activeElement.nextElementSibling 
      : baseEl && document.activeElement.previousElementSibling;
    el.focus();
  }
...
```